# Create work pattern SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I'm looking to create what appears to be quite a simple table in SQL, however, I'm struggling to create it.

The first date at which the work pattern starts is 01/01/1990 (UK date format: dd/mm/yyyy - happy to have this as 1990/01/01 if necessary). The end date of the first period is 8 weeks from the start date (26/02/1990). The start date of the next period is the day after the previous end date (27/02/1990) and so on. I'd want the last end date to be some time in the future (at least 10 years from now).

This is ideally how I want the table to look:

```
+--------+------------+------------+
| Period | Start Date |  End Date  |
+--------+------------+------------+
|      1 | 01/01/1990 | 26/02/1990 |
|      2 | 27/02/1990 | 24/04/1990 |
|      3 | 25/04/1990 | 20/06/1990 |
|      4 | 21/06/1990 | 16/08/1990 |
|      5 | 17/08/1990 | 12/10/1990 |
+--------+------------+------------+
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Whats your current code?

Comment: what do you mean by date format. The database has no date format, dates are stored without a format it is up to your presentation layer to choose a format to show it.

Comment: Do you really define your periods like that? So the first period starts on a Monday and ends on a Monday. The second period starts on a Tuesday and ends on a Tuesday, etc?

Comment: what is your question ? Do you have a  problem with creating the table or with populating it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just adding 8 weeks and not considering the weekends you can follow something like this.

```
DECLARE @tempTable TABLE(
    Period INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    StartDate DateTime,
    EndDate DateTime
);
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = GETDATE();
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME;
DECLARE @currYear INT = DATEPART(YY,@startDate);
DECLARE @endYear INT = @currYear + 10;

WHILE (@currYear <= @endYear)
BEGIN
    SET @endDate = DATEADD(WEEK,8,@startDate);
    INSERT INTO @tempTable (StartDate, EndDate) VALUES(@startDate, @endDate);
    SET @startDate = DATEADD(dd,1,@endDate);
    SET @currYear = DATEPART(YY,@startDate);
END;
SELECT Period, FORMAT(StartDate,'dd/MM/yyyy') AS StartDate, FORMAT(EndDate,'dd/MM/yyyy') AS EndDate FROM @tempTable
```

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE your_table
(
    Period INT,
    StartDate DATE,
    EndDate DATE
)

INSERT INTO your_table
VALUES
(1,'1990-01-01','1990-02-26')
--etc
```